# Javascript code to query an API and return values

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xml

I am working on a chrome plugin in which I will have to query Alexa API with the current URL on the browser if it is among the top 100,000 sites.
I am using Javascript - I have a Python solution but am trying to achieve this in Javascript.

I have tried `xmlhttprequest`, I don't know if I get the code correct and it looks like that's the way to achieve it.

I am new to Javascript and would appreciate commented code.

//--------MY JAVASCRIPT JABBLE-----//

```
var urlDomain = window.location.hostname;
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
 xhr.open("GET", "http://data.alexa.com/data?cli=10&dat=s&url=" + urlDomain, false).read(), "xml").find("REACH")['RANK']
    except TypeError:
        return -1
    rank = int(rank)
    return 1 
    if rank < 100000 
    else 0


//-------THE WORKING PYTHON SOLUTION-----//

def web_traffic(url):
    try:
        rank = \
            bs4.BeautifulSoup(urllib.urlopen("http://data.alexa.com/data?cli=10&dat=s&url=" + url).read(), "xml").find("REACH")['RANK']
    except TypeError:
        return -1
    rank = int(rank)
    return 1 if rank < 100000 else 0
```

The project is a phishing page detection plugin, it returns `-1` if the URL is not ranked in the top 100,000 and `1` if the URL is in the top 100,000 and `0` if its not in the top 100,000 site also.

Comment: That API endpoint doesn't seem to be working anymore. It always returns "Okay", regardless of the input, e.g. http://data.alexa.com/data?cli=10&dat=s&url=http://stackoverflow.com/

Comment: The JavaScript section isn't valid JavaScript at the moment. Before trying to figure out how to query an API, I'd recommend familiarizing yourself with the language in general. [This page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/A_re-introduction_to_JavaScript) has a basic overview of the language and syntax, or there's [this complete guide](https://www.codecademy.com/learn/introduction-to-javascript).

Comment: There are also various guides online to fetching data with JavaScript, such as [this one](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch). Since you're writing an extension and therefore don't need to worry about supporting old browsers, it'll be easiest to use the modern `fetch()` API rather than `XMLHttpRequest`.

Comment: @ecraig12345 am new to JavaScript, I know the code is not valid thats why I called it a jabble lol... thank you for the resource links they will sure be useful. But if I can get a code that works let me just complete that part of the chrome extension.

Comment: @chris, I just noticed alexa doesnt offer that anymore for free... I just checked out some alternatives with open dns....and I also came across a fairly old alexa dump... http://s3.amazonaws.com/alexa-static/top-1m.csv.zip  the open dns dump can be found here http://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/umbrella-static/index.html  do I have to download these, convert and parse as Jason/XML

Answer (score -1):

You can use jQuery AJAX to achieve the same:

(import jQuery.js!)

```
$.ajax({
  method: 'GET',
  url: DOMAIN,
  timeout: 15000,
  dataType: 'xml',
  success: data => {
      // success
  },
  error: err => {
      // error
  }
```

})